# Split String into array of string of length 1 in Swift

Tags: swift, string

Say I have a string here:

```
var str = "Hello"
```

I want to split the string into a array of substrings, each of the substring's length is 1

```
var arr = // ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

I know I can do `arr = Array(str)` to get an array of `Character`s and then use `map` to cast them to an array of `String`s, like this:

```
let arr = Array(str).map { String($0) }
```

Is there anyway I can do without `map`? Or a better way with `map`?

Comment: What's wrong with `map`?  `let arr = str.map(String.init)` does the job nicely.

Comment: `let substrings = str.indices.map{str[$0...$0]}`

Comment: If you insist not to use map, same logic using reduce `let characters = str.indices.reduce([]) { $0 + [str[$1...$1]] }` or using reduce(into:) `let characters = str.indices.reduce(into: []){ $0.append(str[$1...$1]) }`

Comment: The “without map” requirement is silly.

Comment: @vacawama I like your way. Than you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to avoid `map`. There are many ways to get an `Array` of `String`s from a string without using `map`. Just for the fun of it, here are some examples :

```
var str11 = "Hello"

//For character in
var a: [String] = []
for char in str11 { a.append(String(char)) }

//forEach
var b: [String] = []
str11.forEach { b.append(String($0)) }

//while + index
var c: [String] = []
var i = str11.startIndex
while i < str11.endIndex {
    c.append(String(str11[i]))
    i = str11.index(after: i)
}

//filter
var d: [String] = []
_ = str11.filter { char in
    d.append(String(char))
    return false
}

//reduce into
let e: [String] = str11.reduce(into: [String]()) {
    $0.append(String($1))
}

//compactMap
let f: [String] = str11.compactMap { String($0) }

//sorted
var g: [String] = Array(repeating: " ", count: str11.count)
_ = str11.enumerated().sorted {
    ($0.element, g[$0.offset] = String($0.element)).0 < ($1.element, g[$1.offset] = String($1.element)).0
}

//regular expression
var h: [String] = []
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".{1}")
let matches = regex.matches(in: str11,
                            range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (str11 as NSString).length))
for match in matches {
    h.append(String(str11[Range(match.range, in: str11)!]))
}

//makeIterator
var j: [String] = []
var iterator = str11.makeIterator()
while let char = iterator.next() {
    j.append(String(char))
}
```

Comment: OP asked for an array of substrings

Comment: @LeoDabus They did say "*and then use map to cast them to **String***"

Comment: He said he knows he can do it but he doesn't want to

Comment: @LeoDabus I don’t really care about external validation, that’s for kids, someone sad enough wasn’t in the mood for fun or talking. The linked answer does use map. Cool way of using defer though 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vacawama's answer.
This is really nice.
Although this uses map but it's really concise.

```
let arr = str.map(String.init)
```

Comment: shout out again for @vacawama

Comment: This does use `map` ??!

Comment: Yes. By far this is the nicest one out there.

Comment: I don't understand why people keeps downvote my question. I am pretty new to the community.

Comment: OK, I just updated the question. Thanks for all the help from all of you.